# Failed to pick image from gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

The default image picker is "Photos" app, and I'm trying to get the image from it with this code:

```
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
```

Column index is 0, intent data.uriString is content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh6.googleusercontent.com%2Fkq9rt92AVV-kyXilW-42TQGxnlXe5uZ6X8AU6XBW7Vg%3Ds0-d, but filePath is null after cursor.getString call. 
Why and how to handle the image pick?

Comment: I have same problem on a Nexus 4, Android 5.0 :-(

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?